# Python code: "Min" formatting correctly, but "Max"

Tags: python, python-3.x, max, min, weather

I am trying to process a csv file with weather data.

The file is organized so that the first column is the year, second is month, third is day of month, the fourth is the hours (00 to 23 per day), and fifth is hourly dewpoint temperature for each day of the year. Some of the days have temperature values for every hour, and some have a few hours that are -999 or missing.

I am trying to extract the minimum and maximum daily values from this hourly data. To do this, I have an "if" statement sorted by months to identify the number of days per month. Then within the if statement I sort by date to extract the min dewpoint (minDP) and maximum dewpont (maxDP) from the hourly data. To find the minDP and maxDP I have separate min & max functions with the same argument parameters: for each date with hourly data, return the min or max if the dewpoint(s) are greater than -999, otherwise return "M" for "missing" if all hourly data for the day is -999. The minDP section works fine, however, the maxDP always returns missing for all dates and I don't understand why. In the maxDP section, if I change the "max" function to "min" it returns min successfully.

```
for m in months:
    if m == '01' or m =='03' or m == '05' or m == '07' or m == '08' or m == '10' or m == '12':
         dates = ['01','02','03','04','05','06','07','08','09','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21','22','23','24','25','26','27','28','29','30','31']
         for d in dates:

             # For each date extract the minimum dewpoint, print "M" if all values for the date are less than -999
             with open('samplehourlydata.txt', 'r') as f:
                reader = csv.reader(f)
                next(reader)     # Skip header
                MinDP = min(row[4] if row[1] == m and row[2] == d and int(row[4]) > -999 else 'M' for row in reader)

            # For each date extract the maximum dewpoint, print "M" if all values for the date are less than -999
             with open('samplehourlydata.txt', 'r') as f:
                reader = csv.reader(f)
                next(reader)  # Skip header
                MaxDP = max(row[4] if row[1] == m and row[2] == d and int(row[4]) > -999 else 'M' for row in reader)
                print(year, m, d, MinDP, MaxDP)
```

The fact that the max argument is executing the "else" portion of my if statement makes me think that it is doing what I am technically telling it to do. However, I am thinking that I must not be telling it to do what I think I am. However, the fact that simply changing "max" to "min" in the maxDP section returns actual min values seems to reaffirm that the argument is valid...

if it helps, the csv data for just the first day looks like this:

```
yyyy,mm,dd,hour,D.P.
2011,01,01,00, 27
2011,01,01,01, 28
2011,01,01,02, 27
2011,01,01,03, 26
2011,01,01,04, 26
2011,01,01,05, -999
2011,01,01,06, 28
2011,01,01,07, 27
2011,01,01,08, 28
2011,01,01,09, 29
2011,01,01,10, 31
2011,01,01,11, 34
2011,01,01,12, 37
2011,01,01,13, 39
2011,01,01,14, 40
2011,01,01,15, 42
2011,01,01,16, 44
2011,01,01,17, 43
2011,01,01,18, 43
2011,01,01,19, 43
2011,01,01,20, 43
2011,01,01,21, 42
2011,01,01,22, 44
2011,01,01,23, 44
```

and the current output with the erroneous maxDP looks like this:

```
yyyy mm dd MinDP MaxDP
2011 01 01  26 M
```

Thanks for any input.

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code.

Comment: I haven't looked carefully, but it seems you may be taking min/max of strings which will use lexicographic order (where "123" comes before "99" for example). Try converting to numbers? (You won't be able to compare numbers with "M" though.)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
MaxDP = max(row[4] if row[1] == m and row[2] == d and int(row[4]) > -999 else '\0' for row in reader)
```

'\0' is the lowest character

Comment: Thank you. I was not familiar with that kind of lowest character approach

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution (that doesn't verify the year, month, day), but uses the YYY MM DD as a key to a dictionary. The values are held in a list for that year, month and day.

This approach doesn't reopen the file for every day of the month, but summarizes them keyed by the year, month, day.

```
import csv

d = dict()

with open('f0.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader) # drop header
    for row in reader:
        key = ' '.join(row[:3]) # YYYY MM DD
        d.setdefault(key, []).append(int(row[4]))

print ('yyyy mm dd MinDP MaxDP')

for key, vals in d.items():
    if all(v == -999 for v in vals):
        print(key, 'M', 'M')
    else:
        my_max = max(vals)
        my_min = min([v for v in vals if v != -999])
        print(key, my_min, my_max)
```

For your data, I got the result:

```
yyyy mm dd MinDP MaxDP
2011 01 01 26 44
```

UPDATE: The code `d.setdefault(key, []).append(int(row[4]))` just says if the key is seen for the first time, set the *default* value to a list, `[]`, and then append row[4]. If the key has been seen already, it just appends row[4].

There is a brief introduction to dictionaries [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) and looping over them [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques)

Also, here is a link about dictionaries at [geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-dictionary/) and you may find more Python information there by searching.

Also note that when deleting a key and it's values from a dictionary, an exception will be thrown if the key isn't in the dictionary. So, if you are unsure whether a key exists in the dictionary, it is best to check first with:

```
if some_key in some_dict:
    del some_dict[some_key]
```

You can retrieve a value from a dictionary like `var = dict_name[some_key]` provided the key is in the dictionary. If it isn't, you will throw an exception.

In that case, if unsure if the key exists, you can use [get](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get).

Hope these links will get you started with dictionaries. They aren't difficult after you've used them and are one of the most useful data structures in Python (and other languages).

[Search page](https://search.yahoo.com/search?p=geeksfor+geeks+python+dictionaries&fr=yfp-t&fp=1&toggle=1&cop=mss&ei=UTF-8) for dictionaries.

Comment: That helped. I'm not really familiar with using dictionaries, so I'll have to read up on them. Thank you.

Comment: @Ethan Hi, I added an update to my reply (above) to explain what `d.setdefault(key, []).append(int(row[4]))` does. It handles the updating of a dictionary. Hope that it clears some things up for you.

Comment: @Ethan I added some links about dictionaries that may be helpful in my Update section at the bottom of my post.